# Image Rotation in multiple angles in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I have a collection view in which i use image from gallery. 
In collection view cell i have a button on which when user click it rotate the image, now when i click the button it only rotate in 180 degree , I want to rotate the image in right, left angle also.
My code is this for rotating image:

```
- (IBAction)rotatePic:(id)sender 
{

_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);` to make a rotation of 90°.

- M_PI_4 = 45 degrees
- M_PI_2 = 90 degrees
- M_PI   = 180 degrees
- M_PI*2 = 360 degrees

Comment: Bro i want it when user click it should first move to like 90 dgree and if again click it show image to 180 degree and if again click it moves to 360 degree. @Kerberos

Comment: If you want to rotate 90 degrees every time you click on the button you can use this code:
`CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.imageView.transform, M_PI_2);

self.imageView.transform = newTransform;`

Otherwise you can use a counter in the method.

Comment: i want that whenever user click the button no matters how many time the image should  rotate in all four angles as u have given in  answer . It should not move only to one specific angle. @Kerberos

Comment: As already answered you can use a counter and a switch case where you can rotate the image of the degrees you want.
When you complete the circle you can reset the counter.